# Lower bound of minimum eigenvalue of positive definite matrix using the smallest off-diagonal element and largest diagonal element

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization

Consider an $K \times K$ symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ that has the following properties

1. All of its elements are nonnegative and within $0$ and $1$, i.e. $0 < A_{ij} < 1$
2. The smallest element of all its diagonal elements is $d$, i.e. $d = \min_{i} A_{ii}$
3. The largest element of all its off-diagonal elements is $r$, i.e. $r = max_{i, j} A_{ij}$ for all $i \neq j$
4. $d > r$
5. Let $\lambda_K$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

Is there a way to give a lower bound of the minimum eigenvalue of this matrix in terms of $r$ and $d$, like $\lambda_K \ge C\cdot(d - r)$, where $C$ is a constant?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get a quick and crude bound with Gerschgorin Discs-- let $C=K-1$

Comment: @user8675309, thank you for you suggestion, so what your $C$ here?

Comment: let me clarify-- using Gerschorin discs, you can get $\lambda_K \geq d - (K-1)r$

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you.  Hope I can remove the $K-1$